# I always have a "WHERE date" in all my SQL queries. Speed up?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a large table with hundreds of thousands of rows. However only about 50,000 rows are actually "active" and part of my queries, because I only select the rows that have been updated last 14 days with `WHERE crdate > "2014-08-10"`. So to speed up the queries to the table I'm thinking what of the following options (or maybe you have another suggestion?) that is the best one:

1. I can delete all old entries and insert them into a "history" table with a cronjob running every day/week. However this will still make the history table slow if I want to do queries to that one.
2. I can make an index on my "crdate" column. However my dates are in the format of "2014-08-10 06:32:59" so I guess because it is storing so many different values, that index will be quite large(?) and potentially slow(?).

Do you guys have any other suggestion of how I can speed up queries to this table? Is it an bad idea to set an index on a date-column that have so many different values?

Comment: The index will be larger than it needs to be, but it still won't be prohibitively large. I'd certainly add one if I were in your position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st rule of databases. Always have indexes on columns you are filtering on.**

So yes, put an index on `crdate`.

You can also go with a history table in parallel but make sure you put the index on the `crdate` column in the history table too. Having the history table, will allow you to have a smaller index in the main table.

Comment: Does it matter if my `crdate`column is in the "YYYY-MM-DD" format or in "YYYY-MM-DD 15:41:31" format? I mean, does more values slow down the index?

Comment: If you're going with a history table in parallel there won't be any noticeable delay. But if you split the `crdate` in two columns (both having indexes) using one table is fine as you are significantly limiting the size of the indexes

Comment: I just want to know if more potential values in an index makes it slower or not. To speed things up, should I remove the seconds and minutes data if I dont really need it?

Comment: A bigger index always means more time but negligible compared with searching without an index. If you are going to have millions of rows in that table then split the `crdate` in a date and time part. If you are going with a history table as well, you can leave `crdate` whole.

Comment: @MarcusLind With more distinct values an B-Tree index becomes more and more effective. With just a few distinct values it becomes more ineffective - it degenerates. For example a B-Tree index on a `gender` column does not make sense and slows things down rather speeding up. That's a reason why I am not happy with the advice here to _always_ use indexes on columns you're filtering on. For low cardinality columns Bitmap Indexes are useful but MySQL does not support it as far as I know.

Comment: @FabianBarney the rule with indexing columns was a broad general rule on databases. Of course there are exceptions for each type of RDBMS engine and type of data/value the columns will hold.

Comment: @MarcusLind Note: a timestamp (or date) column **does not have** a format. The format is only needed to convert the date value on input or output operations.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to this for future googler's. if you are querying a datatime a more distinct query will result in a more efficient query for example

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateTime = '01/01/2015 00:00:00'
```

Will be faster than:

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateTime = '01/01/2015'
```

I tested this repeatedly on an indexed view(by datetime) of 5 million rows the more distinct query gave me a 1 second quicker response